# What is this Chart name based on description

Tags: charts

I am looking at the name of a chart used in datadog monitor status history.
Once I know the name, my hope it's to be able to find a library that would replicate something equivalent.

Explanation of the chart:

- Each row represent an instance to monitor (here a partner)
- A row is composed of multiple bins
- A bin is characterized by:

  - start (datetime)
  - end (datetime)
  - is_anomalous (boolean)
- If a bin is anomalous, then it's displayed as red, otherwise it's displayed as green.
- The number of bins by row and the start & end datetimes of bins are varying from one row to an another.
- Bonus point if:

  - is_anomalous:boolean can be instead a decimal number and be displayed as a gradiant
  - we can visualize when a bin start and when it ends

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: stacked bar chart - horizontal? [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack), [apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked-100/)

Comment: stacked bar chart (at least the examples provided) is implying that the data serie is having a continuity on multiple rows, which does not match with what I am looking at. What I am looking at is, for a single data serie, the continuity is on a single row.

Comment: Right, it really depends on the environment you're planning to use. Most libraries allow you structure your data independently, e.g., https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profile Also a simpliied Gnatt chart may be a starting point in some cases, e.g., https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart/

Comment: Thank you @kikon, the gantt-chart is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. Just a word of caution about Gantt - in full form it takes a lot of information for the relation *between the horizontal bars* - from the upper bars to the lower ones, since each bar is supposed to represent a stage in the management of a project. I think that might get very annoying to get rid of in some library implementations, while in others you can easily ignore that part, as seems to be the case with the example I gave you from amcharts.